# Define dynamically event handler in Java

Tags: java, arrays, events, event-handling

Assume that I have defined two arrays in Java. The first array has `m` cells and the second has `n` cells. Assume that each cells can have a `0` or `1` value.

In this program every cell of the first array will join one of the cells of the second array, but we do not know which one will be connected to which cell of the second array (This connection is totally logical,e.g. we just know `array1[3]` is related to `array2[7]`).

So now I want to define an event handler for each of these relationship, so when one of the cells fluctuate from 1 to 0, its paired cell fluctuate. Actually I want to define event handler in a run-time and in dynamic way, because before it, I do not know which one of the cells in `array1` will be pair with which one of cells in `array2`.

Is there any solution for this?

If you think I can solve this problem without dynamic event handler please let me know about your solution.

Comment: You cannot listen for array modifications using an event handler in Java.

Comment: you mean that there is not any way to track the changes of array cells? We can not define an event handler to notify us when value of a cell changed?

Comment: Nope.  You would have to create your own object with an event handler and use two Lists to collect however many of the objects you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to solve this without using an event handler.  See if this works for what you are doing.

First, instead of two arrays, let's use two 2D arrays that are `m x 1` and `n x 1`.

```
int[][] array1 = new int[m][];
int[][] array2 = new int[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    array1[i] = new int[] { /* your code */ ? 1 : 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array2[i] = array1[ /* your code */ ];
```

The first `/* your code */` is your condition for choosing to put either `1` or `0` into each element of `array1`.  The second `/* your code */` is your method for deciding which element of `array1` corresponds to each element of `array2`.

Now each element in `array2` is also an element of `array1`, so when you update a value in one of the arrays from `0` to `1`, it is also updated in the other array.

```
array2[7] = array1[3];
array1[3][0] = 0;
System.out.println(array2[7][0]); // prints "0"
array1[3][0] = 1;
System.out.println(array2[7][0]); // prints "1"
```

Comment: I think your solution is my answer, can you please describe your answer in details? I do not know what I should write instead of  `/*your code*/`... can you help me to understand it??

Comment: @Chavoosh I've added the explanation into the answer.  The reason I can't tell you what to write in place of `/* your code */` is that you haven't told us how you decide which elements are `1` or `0`, or how you choose the correspondence between elements of `array1` and `array2`.

Comment: Thanks dear @Nathaniel for your response...I Have another question, in `for` section, you use `array1` and `array2` by one `[]` while you define 2d array, what this mean?

Comment: Dear @Nathaniel, I do not know how I can say thanks to you. Finally I got what you said and it works! Thanks a lot..... 
Just one another thing, each time that I change value of a cell in `array1`, its pair cell in `array2` will change, now how I can find out which cell in `array2` changed exactly that time?

Comment: @Chavoosh As you've probably figured out, a 2D array in Java is just an array of arrays. When you change the value of entry `j` in `array1`, the entry in `array2` that changes will be entry `i` from your assignment `array2[i] = array1[j];`.

Comment: I know this, but assume that we don`t know which 2 cells are connected. In your example we connect cells manually, but in my program it is totally random. So how I can find out that the pair cell of a cell is what??

Comment: @Chavoosh When you link the cells, you could create an additional array to map indices from the first array to the second.  However, if there's any reason to know how the cells are paired, then why even bother to keep two arrays?  The mapping could replace the second array and make your problem much simpler.