# Event handler for array

Tags: arrays, events, event-handling, actionlistener

Have we event handler,event listener,action listener or any like these, for `array`in any compile-based language (e.g. Java,c++,c)?

I am searching a way to track the changes of an `array`. So when value of a cell changed the listener notify me about this change and the cell number that this changed occurred for it.

is there any language or any option for this problem?

Comment: You can implement it in whatever language you like that support events C# does that very well in my opinion

Comment: you mean that I can define event listener for `array`?? You know, I asked some question like this yesterday about Java here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839758/define-dynamically-event-handler-in-java/19843604?noredirect=1#comment29517550_19843604)
but every one said it is impossible.

Comment: not for an array object but you can implement it using a custom type or any specialized collections why wouldn't you want to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

If you do not want to use a custom type you can have a look at this implementation to observe when an array is changed : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162966/Observing-Changes-to-an-Underlying-Array

Here is an example from Microsoft in C# that does what you are looking for with an ArrayList

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

```
// events1.cs
using System;
namespace MyCollections 
{
   using System.Collections;

   // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
   public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

   // A class that works just like ArrayList, but sends event
   // notifications whenever the list changes.
   public class ListWithChangedEvent: ArrayList 
   {
      // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
      // elements of the list change.
      public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

      // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
      protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) 
      {
         if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, e);
      }

      // Override some of the methods that can change the list;
      // invoke event after each
      public override int Add(object value) 
      {
         int i = base.Add(value);
         OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
         return i;
      }

      public override void Clear() 
      {
         base.Clear();
         OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
      }

      public override object this[int index] 
      {
         set 
         {
            base[index] = value;
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
         }
      }
   }
}

namespace TestEvents 
{
   using MyCollections;

   class EventListener 
   {
      private ListWithChangedEvent List;

      public EventListener(ListWithChangedEvent list) 
      {
         List = list;
         // Add "ListChanged" to the Changed event on "List".
         List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
      }

      // This will be called whenever the list changes.
      private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
      }

      public void Detach() 
      {
         // Detach the event and delete the list
         List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
         List = null;
      }
   }

   class Test 
   {
      // Test the ListWithChangedEvent class.
      public static void Main() 
      {
      // Create a new list.
      ListWithChangedEvent list = new ListWithChangedEvent();

      // Create a class that listens to the list's change event.
      EventListener listener = new EventListener(list);

      // Add and remove items from the list.
      list.Add("item 1");
      list.Clear();
      listener.Detach();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well here we have `list` and we can track the changes on a `list`, but I want to track the changes of an `array`.

Comment: Yes that's true I guess because array are primitive types they are not listenable but why couldn't you do that with a custom type ?

Comment: Well in my program, I have rigid space-constraint, so using list instead of array is not suitable from this point.

Comment: Then maybe the reference I provided to this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162966/Observing-Changes-to-an-Underlying-Array may help you.